# How to do relative jumps in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack-overflow

I'm following [Aleph One's awesome introduction to smashing the stack](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html), but I've gotten stuck running one of the example programs he has.  The issue is that when I compile the line `jmp 0x2a`, and disassemble it, that exact line is produced, whereas in aleph's code, it is translated to `jmp    0x800015f <main+47>`.  How do I force gcc to make this a relative jump and not an absolute one (which is what I think is going on).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `0x2a`.  That looks like an absolute address, but what you want is a relative address.

That can be accomplished by  labeling the destination and jumping to that:  assemblers prefer generating a relative jump most of the time.  Or use a relative address.  Most assemblers accept something similar to `.+0x2a` where `.` is a symbol meaning the current instruction pointer.  Some use `$` instead.